# Joomla virtuemart sample data installation

Tags: joomla

I have installed joomla and virtuemart without any sample data. Now I have some sample data for virtuemarrt in .sql format. How can I install those sample data now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to run this file in your database management tool, most likely phpMyAdmin. Once in phpMyAdmin, select the database that your Joomla is installed in, then click the SQL tab and copy and paste the contents of the file and click Go. You could also click the Import if you want to browse to the file and run it that way.